# Кастомный класс селекта для DateTimeType на Symfony 3

Tags: html, css, symfony3

Доброго всем времени суток. 
Я кастомизирую форму, сгенерированную автоматически с помощью генератора CRUD. Пытаюсь проставить css стили для добавляемых на форму элементов, и вообще сделать её более благопристойно выглядещей. Вот параметры которые я скармливаю конструктору формы:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('timeStart', null, ['attr'  => [
                'data-style'=>"btn-success", 
                'class' => 'selectpicker'
                ] ] )
            ->add('timeEnd', null, ['attr'  => [
                'data-style'=>"btn-danger", 
                'class' => 'selectpicker'
                ] ] )
            ->add('parentlist', null, ['attr'  => [
                'data-style'=>"btn-primary", 
                'class' => 'selectpicker'
                ]] );
}
```

Поле parentlist - это простой селектбокс, который выбирает список к которому принадлежит задача. Ему я без проблем проставил класс .selectpicker и бутстраповский плагин его подхватил и переработал в красивый. А для полей timeStart и timeEnd стоит тип виджета DateTimeType, и соответственно селектбоксы добавляются другими отдельными виджетами. И соответственно когда я проставляю этим полям класс .selectpicker то этот класс уходит не к селектбоксам, как у parentlist, а div'у который их всех объеденяет.
Что мне сделать, чтоб кастомизировать селектбоксы на обычном DateTimeType виджете? Может для виджетов полей можно редактировать шаблони, из которых они рендерятся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У поля с типом DateTimeType есть опции [`widget`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#widget), [`date_widget`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#date-widget) и [`time_widget`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#time-widget) с помощью которых можно задавать тип получаемого виджета (текстовое поле, набор инпутов, набор селектов).

Кроме того, если стандартный рендеринг виджета вас не устраивает, вы можете:

- [рендерить виджеты вручную](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/rendering.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand)
- использовать собственные или перегружать существующие шаблоны фрагментов форм (строк, виджетов, меток и пр.) используя [темы](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)
- [кастоизировать конкретное поле](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field) непосредственно в месте его использования

Более подробного ответа дать не получится, так как предоставленной вами информации явно для этого не достаточно.